# Visual Studio 2015 cannot load project because of long node_module path

Tags: visual-studio-2015, node-modules

My web app has a node_modules folder and some of the files have long paths.

```
wwwroot\node_modules\lite-server\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\localtunnel\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator
```

VS2015 won't load my web project because the paths of some files are too long. Is there a way to exclude the node_modules folder from being added to my VS project?

UPDATE

I found out that setting up Angular2 in Visual Studio 2015 requires another approach. I followed the steps in [Starting Angular 2 in ASP.NET 5 with TypeScript using Visual Studio 2015](http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/) and I didn't get any build issues anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two actions to take:

1. if possible, switch to npm v3, that has a flat directory structure, as opposed to previous version having a nested directory structure.
2. beside that, apply workarounds so that VS effectively ignores the `node_modules` folder. Even if flat, it cause unresponsiveness anyway. Those workarounds are discussed in this [Asp.Net tooling issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/94) on GitHub. The main gist is:

   1. to flag the directory as hidden from Windows Explorer, move it away then move it back again under web project.
   2. Also, to manually edit `.xproj` so to add `node_modules` directory to the invisible items:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <DnxInvisibleFolder Include="buildOutput\" />
  <DnxInvisibleFolder Include="typings\" />
  <DnxInvisibleFolder Include="node_modules\" />
</ItemGroup>
```